# how to change pdf favicon/icon name in laravel/html

Tags: php, html, laravel

[image]

I am using laravel app, I have bunch of pdf data in mysql when I click to open it in new tab using target="_blank" its icon/favicon name will be changed rondomnly. Can you help me how to give a name to pdf favicon/icon on choice. Following is code which I am using to open pdf file.

**CODE:**

```
 <a class="download" target="_blank" href="{{ asset('download/ca/'.$doc->file_name) }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control the page tab and icon you cannot use _blank since that is the default browser domain where it chooses icon and title, here I have simply used a html page without js window open or other loss of controls like target about:_blank.

Head

```
    <title> A brief, clear, informative, and unique title</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="myicon.png">
```

Body
... `<iframe class="frame" type="application/pdf" src="adobe_supplement_iso32000.pdf#view=FitH&toolbar=0" title="testPdf"> </iframe>`
...

[image: ![enter image description here]

**If I use _blank I will get the system default icon and if available meta title**

[image]
[image]